# Cannot set variables in generated CMake script

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am trying to get the output from the invocation of an executable in `CMake` as a string for processing in the build system. It is a list of test suites that I will add to the CTest tool using `add_test`.

In `CMakeLists.txt`

```
...(After adding the mlpack_test target)...
configure_file(generate_test_names.cmake.in generate_test_names.cmake)
add_custom_command(TARGET mlpack_test
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P generate_test_names.cmake
)
```

In `generate_test_names.cmake.in`

```
function(get_names)
  message("Adding tests to the test suite")
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/mlpack_test --list_content
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
  message(STATUS "FOO='${FOO}'")
endfunction()

get_names()
```

The script gets executed, and I can see the output from `mlpack_test --list_content` in the `stdout` of the build. But `FOO` is still an empty string.

The output :

```
Adding tests to the test suite
ActivationFunctionsTest*
    TanhFunctionTest*
    LogisticFunctionTest*
    SoftsignFunctionTest*
    IdentityFunctionTest*
    RectifierFunctionTest*
    LeakyReLUFunctionTest*
    HardTanHFunctionTest*
    ELUFunctionTest*
    SoftplusFunctionTest*
    PReLUFunctionTest*
-- FOO=''
```

Why is the argument to `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` not initialised with the `stdout` of the process executed?

Comment: Probably, what you see in the build output is the **stderr** of the executed process. You may pass additional option `ERROR_VARIABLE FOO` for `execute_process`, so its **whole output** will be redirected into *FOO* variable.

Comment: I tried you suggestion, but `FOO` is still empty. I also noticed that I am unable to define any variable in the script, ie. even after `set(myvar 1)` `myvar` is empty.

Comment: Command `configure_file` replaces **all occurences** of `${var}`... You may want to pass `@ONLY` parameter to the command, so it will replace only `@var@` instances. BTW, you may check content of generated file `generate_test_names.cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot! Adding @ONLY worked. Should have checked the documentation for `configure_file` more closely.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you mind adding that as an answer to the question? :)

Comment: Could you reword your question, so **actual problem** ("variables do not work in the generated script" or such) will be introduced? So, your question will be useful for futher readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generate CMake script with `configure_file`, it is better to use *@ONLY* option for that command:

```
configure_file(generate_test_names.cmake.in generate_test_names.cmake @ONLY)
```

In that case only `@var@` references will be replaced with variable's values, but `${var}` references remains *unchanged*:

```
function(get_names)
  message("Adding tests to the test suite")
  # CMAKE_BINARY_DIR will be replaced with the actual value of the variable
  execute_process(COMMAND @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/bin/mlpack_test --list_content
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
  # But FOO will not be replaced by 'configure_file'.
  message(STATUS "FOO='${FOO}'")
endfunction()

get_names()
```